# ASP.NET Membership.ValidateUser() always return "false"

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

Here is my web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="MYbdName" 
         applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         passwordFormat="Clear" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="4" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I even hardcoded the username and password:

```
 bool b = Membership.ValidateUser("user@mail.com", "pass123");
```

When i perform a select on database i get the correct user.

User isAproved = true

User isLockedout = 0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `applicationName` property when configuring ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and other Providers. In your web.config, it's missing:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="MYbdName" 
         applicationName="/"   <----------   Missing applicationName
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         passwordFormat="Clear" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="4" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" /> 
  </providers>
</membership>
```

You can try to get the value here

```
public bool Login(string userName, string password)
{
    var provider = Membership.Provider;
    string name = provider.ApplicationName; // Get the application name here

    return Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
}
```

or open up the `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_Applications` tables within the `ASPNETDB` database and figure out what application name was used when creating the users and other data during development (look in the `aspnet_Application` table to work this out).

Then correctly set the property in your web.cofig:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="MYbdName" 
             applicationName="MyAppName"   <----------   correct
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             passwordFormat="Clear" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="4" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" /> 
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

For more details, read this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx) from Scott-Gu's blog.

Answer (score 1):

For other people having this issue, also make sure you are using the same machine key across projects that was used when creating/saving the user passwords:

```
<machineKey validationKey="x" decryptionKey="x" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

More info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx