# Membership.ValidateUser always return false on when published on IIS

Tags: membership-provider

Membership.ValidateUser methods works on development server but when we publish the same code on IIS it always returns false even if we give valid user credentials.

Please see below code from config:

```
 <add name="membershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="AspMemberShip" applicationName="Service"/>
```

I have also seen few posts on this but none of them helped me, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

we have to give applicationName in config same as we have in aspnet_applications table.
below post helped me :
[ASP.NET Membership.ValidateUser() always return "false"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098194/asp-net-membership-validateuser-always-return-false)